# Read and process large text files ~100Mb each

Tags: c#, performance, backgroundworker, streamreader

I have a list of large text files to process. I wonder which is the fastest method, because reading line by line is slow.
I have something like that:

```
int cnt = this.listView1.Items.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < this.listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.listView1.Items[i].Text.ToString(),             FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
     while (reader.Peek() != -1)
          {
             //code part
          }
}
```

I read about using blocks(like 100k lines each) via backgroundworkers with multiple threads would help, but I don't know how to implement it. Or if you have better ideas to improve the performance ... your expert advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: If it's only 100 megs I'd load the whole thing into memory with `File.ReadAllLines` and call it a day.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx  Are you trying to process multiple files at the same time?

Comment: You "wonder"? Why wonder?  Just test it!  Also, you don't dispose of your `FileStream`.  Define "slow" for us.  What are the numbers?  What is the sample size?  There is plenty of legwork to be done here and it would be good for you to practice the basics of performance testing/tuning.

Comment: 100 MB is not a large text file. :)

Comment: I am a beginner in c# and also a new member on this site, so sorry if I made some mistakes regarding the tags.

Comment: Reading a file all in first, and only then starting to process it, is probably not the fastest way to proceed - it is merely convenient.

Comment: It seems that you are reluctant to answer questions in comments. It is better to delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are processing files line by line. You also said that loading of files is faster than processing them. There are few ways you can do what you need. One for example:

Create a thread that reads files one by one, line by line. Sequentially, because when doing this in parallel you'll only hammer your HDD and possibly get worse results. You can use `Queue<string>` for that. Use `Queue.Enqueue()` to add lines you've red.

Run another thread that is processing the queue. Use `Queue.Dequeue()` to get (and remove) lines from beginning of your queue. Process the line and write it to the output file. Eventually you can put processed lines in another queue or list and write them at once when you finish processing.

If order of lines in output file is not important you can create as many threads as you have CPU cores (or use `ThreadPool` class) to do the processing (that would speed up things significantly).

[Edit]
If order of lines in the output file is important you should limit line processing to one thread. Or process them in parallel using separate threads and implement mechanism that would control output order. For example you may do that by numbering lines you read from input file (the easy way) or processing lines by each thread in chunks of n-lines and writing output chunk by chunk in the same order you started processing threads.

Comment: the idea sounds very interesting and I'm gonna test it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First you need to decide what is your bottleneck - I/O (reading the files) or CPU (processing them). If it's I/O, reading multiple files concurrently is not going to help you much, the most you can achieve is have one thread read files, and another process them. The processing thread will be done before the next file is available.

I agree with @asawyer, if it's only 100MB, you should read the file entirely into memory in one swoop. You might as well read 5 of them entirely into memory, it's really not a big deal.

EDIT: After realizing all the files are on a single hard-drive, and that processing takes longer than reading the file.

You should have on thread reading the files sequentially. Once a file is read, fire up another thread that handles the processing, and start reading the second file in the first thread. Once the second file is read, fire up another thread, and so on.

You should make sure you don't fire more processing threads than the numbers of cores you have, but for starters just use the thread-pool for this, and optimize later.

You're missing a little bit of performance, because the time you spend reading the first file is not used for any processing. This should be neglible, reading 100MBs of data to memory shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: If the file processing is indeed CPU-intensive, reading in whole files before starting to process the data is not going to be the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Can I use File.ReadAllLines in a backgroundworker with more than 2 threads? will it speed up the process? I'm trying to process over 5 millions records per hour.

Comment: @SamReina unless the files are all on different disks, you should read the files in in one thread and queue the file objects to a threadpool/TPL for processing.  If you try to call File.ReadAllLines in multiple threads against files on one disk, there will be problems!

Comment: That depends on your storage. If it's one mechanical disk, then no - it's not going to speed anything up. On an SSD it might. On enterprise-grade storage it will speed things up. You should try to read two files in parallel and see if it's faster.

Comment: @MartinJames all the files are on same HDD.

Comment: So don't bother reading them in parallel. Read the files sequentially. You can do the processing in a background thread (or more than one, if processing is longer than reading).

Comment: @zmbq yes, the processing takes longer than reading. I'm trying to find the best solution to process the whole files as quick as possible. I don't know how to make it do parallel processing and which method is faster. Every second is vital for the whole performance.

Answer (score -1):

here is a simple threading code you can use: (.Net 4)

```
//firstly get file paths from listview so you won't block the UI thread
List<string> filesPaths = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < this.listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
     filesPaths.Add(listView1.Items[i].Text.ToString());
}


//this foreach loop will fire 50 threads at same time to read 50 files
Parallel.ForEach(filesPaths, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 }, (filepath, i, j) =>
{    
     //read file contents
     string data = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

     //do whatever you want with the contents

});
```

not tested though...

Comment: Only one thread should read the data to prevent disk thrashing.

Comment: its up 2 him now... personally I'd just use 1 thread and a for loop that's all.

Comment: I'm trying to make an email validator which will process many and large email lists and remove from each line the invalid ones based on a regex. I don't think it's a good idea to load all files in memory and process them and also reading line by line is slow. I have tried different options with stopwatch but none of my solutions were good, so if you ever had a similar problem and found a good solution for it please share.

Comment: this method won't load all files to the memory. it will load 50 files.. you can decrease it if you want to 2 or 3.. try it and if you are satisfied with it then you don't need worry about the other stuff..